# Faster way to send SMTP emails in Perl?

Tags: perl, smtp

We use SMTP to send out our emails from my website. Built up using **Email::MIME**, and then **Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP** to pass it along to our SMTP server for sending:

```
my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
    host => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port => 465,
    ssl => 1,
    sasl_username => 'hello@foo.com',
    sasl_password => 'xxxx'
});

sendmail($email,{ to  => ['andy@foo.com'] });
```

My issue is that its sooooo bloody slow! (it takes at least 4-5 seconds per email, and if you are sending one email to the client + one email to us (the admin), thats 10 seconds. We keep getting people thinking the site is broken as it appears to hang

So my question - how can I send the SMTP emails, without the Perl script having to hang? I don't really care about error catching. The main issue is just getting the emails out as fast as possible

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious approach would be to not actually send the email from the web application. Instead, write the information about the email into a job queue and have another job (probably running from `cron`) that looks at the queue and sends any emails that need to be sent. That way the web page returns immediately and the users get their mail within a few minutes.

Last time I tried something like this, [The Schwartz](https://metacpan.org/pod/TheSchwartz) was one of the most recommended job queue managers. It's possible there's something that people would recommend now.

Comment: We‘re using a local mailserver as this job queue. This has the advantage of proven code (the local MTA) and no interface change.